# Handling exceptions using tryCatch inside future.apply::future_lapply

Tags: r, r-future

I want to reattempt failing `readLines` fetches using `tryCatch`. This works as expected, as long as I don't wrap it inside a `future.apply::future_lapply` call for processing a list or vector.

The problem can be reproduced using this code:

```
read_lines_retrying <- function(url, attempts = 5, throttle = 5) {
    result <- NA
    while (is.na(result) && 0 < attempts) {
        attempts <- attempts - 1
        result <- tryCatch(
            {
                readLines(url)
            },
            error = function(cond) {
                message("caught error:")
                message(cond)
                message("")
                Sys.sleep(throttle)
                return(NA)
            }
        )
    }
    if (is.na(result)) {
        stop(paste("could not get URL ", url))
    }
    return(result)
}

urls <- c("http://nonexistant.nonexistant")

future.apply::future_lapply(urls, read_lines_retrying)
```

Of course, the code is meant to retry on transient `readLines` failures, while the example URL will always fail, but this way problem can be most easily seen. When using `lapply` instead of `future.apply::future_lapply`, it takes at least 5 seconds to complete because it waits 5 seconds after each of the 5 attempts. This in not the case with `future.apply::future_lapply`, demonstrating that the exception handling doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get `tryCatch` to work inside `future.apply::future_lapply`?

Comment: As explained in my answer below, it is incorrect to use `message(cond)` here. The proper way to output the error message is to use `message(conditionMessage(cond))`.

Answer (score 2):

Author of **futureverse** here: This is an interesting problem.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```r
boom <- function(x) {
  tryCatch(stop("boom"), error = function(cond) {
    message(1); message(cond); message(2)
  })
}  

y <- lapply(1L, FUN = boom)
## 1
## boom2

y <- future.apply::future_lapply(1L, FUN = boom)
## 1
## Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : boom
```

We can even reproduce this with individual futures:

```r
> y <- boom(1)
## 1
## boom2

> f <- future::future(boom(1))
> y <- future::value(f)
## 1
## Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) ## : boom
```

First of all, it turns out that it `message(cond)` that trigger this odd behavior. If you instead, for instance, use `message(conditionMessage(cond))`, it works fine.

UPDATE 2022-03-01: After asking about this on R-devel (thread 'message() and warning() circumvent calling handlers and signal the original class, e.g. an error' on 2022-03-01 (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2022-March/081515.html)), I conclude that using `message(e)` where `e` is an error condition is incorrect and that one **should use `message(conditionMessage(e))`**.

Technical details below:

What happens is that `message(cond)` end up re-signalling the caught error (= `cond`).  And, despite `message()` is muffling the error signal internally, it turns out that the future still detects it and takes it as a definite error.

I have a hunch what might be happening, but I cannot promise a quick solution.  I'm now tracking this in https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/507.  Until resolved, the workaround is: "avoid resignaling the error you just caught", i.e. don't call `message(cond)` or `warning(cond)` on an error condition.

Thanks a bunch for reporting this important issue.

PS. Please consider https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions for future discussions, because I'm only skimming StackOverflow occasionally.